# Optimization Problem for Spheres and Triangular Prism

Tags: optimization, volume

I study my optimization midterm. I saw a question in the problem set but I could not solve the question. I solve the question with Euler's geometry and find a solution. But I need a general type of optimization problem solution, which is the form of;

Minimize "Volume"

Subject to "Constraints"

In addition, I found the volume and I put the coordinates with respect to the volume that I found. I might accept that the area of the triangular prism is equilateral triangle.

Here is the question;

Given 2 spheres of radia 1<2, determine the coordinates of the largest volume triangular prism that can be inscribed inside the volume between the spheres.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I explain the problem more detailed, thanks.